# Helium gas expand isobaric isothermal

Tags: thermodynamics, gas-laws, enthalpy

If $4\ \mathrm{mol}$ helium gas expand against constant pressure in isothermal process, how can calculate $W$?

Is it $W=-nRT\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}$ as defined by isothermal or is it $W=-p\left(V_2-V_1\right)$ as define from isobaric?

Also, is enthalpy equal to $0$ in such process?

Comment: Since the process is isothermal ($q=0$) and isobaric, then we can say that $\Delta H = 0$ since at constant pressure $\Delta H = q$.

Comment: i also thought ike that but then i statred to consider that atually isothermal mean dT=0 and not Dq/

Comment: Ran, you are right that isothermal means that dT = 0.  Heat transfer generally occurs in isothermal processes, so Q is not zero.

Comment: The "constant pressure" in the question is probably meant to refer to the atmosphere, not necessarily the helium.  If the helium were at constant temperature, constant number of moles, _and_ constant pressure, how would it be expanding???

Comment: actually it mention constant external pressure of 2 atm and isothermal expand under 320k...

Answer (score 2):

If the helium is expanding isothermally against a constant external pressure $P_{ext}$, the work is calculated as
$$w = -P_{ext}(V_2 - V_1)$$
This process is irreversible. The first expression you gave for work is (sort of) the expression for work for a *reversible* isothermal ideal gas expansion.

**If helium is assumed to be an ideal gas**, then $\Delta U = 0$ because the process is isothermal. You have $q = -w$ (and not zero) for this process. $\Delta H$ will be zero too, since $$\Delta H = \Delta U + \Delta(PV) = \Delta U + nR\Delta T = 0$$.

Comment: thanks. if helium no consider ideal gas i assume cannot calculate dH. correct?

Comment: Both ΔU and ΔH will be small but nonzero if the gas isn't ideal; you can compute them if you use the equation of state for the gas.